# Lots of strange IP addresses in my Windows Firewall logs. Concern?

Tags: windows, firewall, logging

Was trying to debug a Samba sharing issue with Mac OS X so I turned on logging for my Windows Firewall.  I didn't expect a lot of conections but the thing filled up quickly.  Here's a sample:

```
2009-12-21 08:49:32 OPEN-INBOUND TCP 192.168.0.4 192.168.0.3 56335 139 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:49:33 OPEN-INBOUND TCP 192.168.0.4 192.168.0.3 56337 139 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:50:02 OPEN UDP 192.168.0.3 68.87.73.242 1389 53 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:50:02 CLOSE TCP 192.168.0.3 212.96.161.238 1391 80 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:50:02 OPEN UDP 192.168.0.3 68.87.71.226 60290 53 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:50:02 OPEN TCP 192.168.0.3 212.96.161.238 1391 80 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:50:02 OPEN TCP 192.168.0.3 212.96.161.238 1393 80 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:50:04 CLOSE TCP 192.168.0.3 212.96.161.238 1393 80 - - - - - - - - -
2009-12-21 08:50:41 CLOSE UDP 192.168.0.3 192.168.0.4 137 50300 - - - - - - - - -
```

I can pick out the local IP addresses (192.168.0.3 is my Windows XP machine, 192.169.0.4 is Mac OS X) as I debug the Samba issue.  But some of the others resolve to Comcast (my ISP) and others resolve to weird hosts like van-dns.com and navisite.net. It doesn't look like any connection sent/received any bytes. I used the reference here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758040%28WS.10%29.aspx.

Is it a cause for concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log you have shown, it looks like standard port 80 outbound connections to `212.96.161.238`.  I don't see any problem there, as it looks like its from your machine, here is a whois: http://www.ip-adress.com/whois/212.96.161.238 looks like AVG updates? 
http://www.robtex.com/dns/update.avg.com.html (notice the ip in the list)

I don't see any concerns there, unless you have more logs showing something else, I wouldn't worry about it, standard TCP traffic.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess it was just the sheer volume that got me thinking.

Comment: @gmoore, you're new to SU, but if this is the answer, click the checkbox :P  and a vote up wouldn't hurt either.. thanks! :)

Comment: I hear you, just seeing if anyone else chimes in :)